# How to Wireless Project only to Another PC Only In the Wireless LAN Network?

Tags: wireless-networking, display, multiple-monitors, miracast

I am trying to project to another PC. Anytime, I want to project my laptop to another PC,  a whole list of PCs appear from my apartment complex :) . How do I restrict this list only to computers in personal  wireless lan network? Afraid one day, will press the wrong pc, and someone else can see my screen.

https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/turn-windows-10-pc-into-wirelss-display